# What Unicode Transformation Format is being represented when just Unicode is written?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Many programs will supply one or more of the following as file encoding formats: **UTF-8**, **UTF-16**, **UTF-32** and simply **Unicode**. How do I know what Unicode Transformation Format **Unicode** is referring to? I'm assuming it correlates to to one of the 8/16/32 formats but I have not been able to find that on the Unicode website.

Comment: None of them, and all of them. Primarily it indicates that the program's authors know very little about Unicode.

Comment: When Microsoft says Unicode, they generally mean little-endian UTF-16 (or UCS2).

Comment: @delnan Microsoft gives you an option to import in Unicode or UTF-X :D

Comment: @CodesInChaos how would you know that is what they're referring to? Btw that is what sparked this question.

Comment: @GovindRai Because Microsoft does so consistently. That's probably a historic accident. Microsoft introduced unicode at a time when UTF didn't exist yet and used the natural choice of UCS-2 (each codepoint encoded using a 16 bit word).

Comment: I agree with delnan's comment. The only thing you can reliably infer from that, is that the author of the software doesn't know what he is talking about, and you should probably not use it to process any non-7-bit-ASCII text.

Comment: @GovindRai Because they explicitly state what they mean in the [system documentation for Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "Unicode-enabled functions[...] use UTF-16 (wide character) encoding, which is the most common encoding of Unicode and the one used for native Unicode encoding on Windows operating systems."

Comment: In the .NET Framework, `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Unicode")` returns code page 1200, better known as UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unicode** is a standard that defines  a list of abstract characters, rendering rules, code points, composition rules, and encoding systems. For example:

- the [small greek epsilon](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b5/index.htm) is the character U+03B5
- the [small c with a cedilla](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm) is the character U+00E7, but also the the small C U+0063 combined with the cedilla U+0327

**UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF32** are encoding formats for unicode characters on 8,16, or 32 bit integers.  It should be added that when looking at the byte streams (e.g. files), UTF-16 and UTF-32 have both a big endian (BE) and a little endian (LE) variant.

So speaking of unicode encoding is misleading: there is not a single one.  But there are common usage of this term:

- on [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081.aspx), when you say [UNICODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131.aspx), it is assumed that it's UTF-16 encoding. In the windows API, the default unicode encoding uses a `wchar_t` which is mapped to a 16 bit integer.
- on [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10051588/3723423), the preferred encoding for unicode is UTF-8. There's by the way an [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) manifest that explains the rationale behind and try to promote this practice.